# How to remove top padding from Opera in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, opera, fullscreen

When i make Opera maximized in Windows 10, it does not really become maximized. I understand this because when i move mouse to the top of screen and click tabs it does not work, i feel like there is a small padding there. If i move my mouse couple of pixels below it does work though.

This happened after i reinstalled my Windows 10. Chrome and Edge does not have same problem.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you double click the padding that is above the tab?

Comment: It minimize the window

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed after i have installed driver of my AMD video card.